# How to ignore `Content-disposition: attachement` header to embed a PDF in <object> element?

Tags: javascript, html, http, content-disposition

I'm requesting an API to get an URL to a PDF document. I want it to be displayed in the browser to users, using `<object type="application/pdf" data="url-to-pdf"></object>`.

So, when I create a link with `<a href="">` to the URL the API gave me, a new tab is open in the browser with the PDF, everything works fine. I can even add the `download` attribute to the `<a>` and the PDF is downloaded automatically. However, when I put it in an `<object>`, instead of being displayed at it is the case usually, the PDF is open in a new tab and the `<object>`  element is empty in the screen.

The headers of the response from the API are:
[image]

And the response itself is binary (which is expected, the file is a PDF).

Does anybody understand why it's not working for this URL specifically? The differences I see in the headers response, compare to a normal PDF that works, is the `Content-Disposition` attribute, the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, the cache-control being private... Can any of this has an effect? I assume it's the `Content-Disposition: attachment` which is resulting on the file being open in a tab instead of inside the `<object>`. Is there any way to force this header to be ignored? Can we maybe imagine a hack where we first fetch it in JS and then put the answer back in `<object>` with `data:`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Content-Disposition` is authoritative here.

Comment: Could be possible by intercepting the request using a service worker, and then giving a modified response, I suppose? https://medium.com/@maulanamaleek/intercept-http-request-using-serviceworker-b6ef23f97d1f